# Construction of self-dual codes

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

A code $C$ is a self-dual code if $C=C^{\perp}$ where $C^{\perp}$ is the dual of $C$.

Consider $C$ is a linear code of length $2n$ over finite field $GF(2^q)$ with generator matrix $G=[I_n\mid A]$ where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$ and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. From $G$ we get the parity-check matrix of $C$ is $H=[ A^T\mid I_n]$.

*My question:* $C$ is a self-dual code if and only if $AA^T=I_n$.

*My try:* If $C$ be a self-dual then $G=H$ and because we have $GH^T=0$ then $GG^T=0$ which results that $I_n+AA^T=0$. Now if $AA^T=I_n$ then $GG^T=0$ which implies that $G=H$.

Is my proof correct?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Looks ok to me. That's the main point anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How could we prove that this characterization of self-dual codes is only available over the field $GF(2^q)$?

Comment: @Lecter I suggest to see Lemma 1 in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1071579718301059) to find your solution.

Comment: @Amin235 Oh, I'd like to ask for fully understand, what is the rate of a code? Anyways, I'd like to ask why this characterization of self-dual codes is true over the field GF(q) as far as you don't use this in the demostration

Comment: @Lecter To start to find out more about this types of codes, Please read carefully [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4595330).